# How to set image with binding for onMouseOut on Angular button

Tags: angular, image, button, binding, onmouseout

I need a **button** in **Angular**. For this button I will set a **image** (icon) by **binding**. On hover the image should change. On event onMouseOut it should set back to the binded image.

Using the event onMouseOut I get the error

*NG8002: Can't bind to 'onMouseOut' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.*

I tried

- <button src='...
- <button ..><img ...
- <input type="image" ...

and get allways the same error.

**How can I use the onMouseOut with binding on a angular button.**

```html
<input type="image" onclick="onUp()" 
src="/assets/icons/{{imgUp}}.png" 
onMouseOver="this.src='/assets/icons/up-hover.png'" 
onMouseOut="this.src='/assets/icons/{{imgUp}}.png'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a element reference like i have created imgElem below and use it.

```
<input
  #imgElem
  type="image"
  onclick="onUp()"
  src="/assets/icons/{{ imgUp }}.png"
  (mouseenter)="imgElem.src = '/assets/icons/up-hover.png'"
  (mouseleave)="imgElem.src = '/assets/icons/{{imgUp}}.png'"
/>
```

Comment: It's not working for me.

Comment: any error? can you please give the issue.

Comment: At the mouseleave comes a 404 and "Cannot GET /assets/icons/%7B%7BimgUp%7D%7D.png" The name of the image file is cryptic instead of "up.png" or "up-active.png". At the src -img the binding works fine.

Comment: 404 means the url of image doesn't exist. make sure image is available at that url.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is setting the image allways with Typescript:

```html
<input type="image" [src]="imgPathUp" (click)="onUp()" 
(mouseenter)="onUpHover()"  (mouseleave)="onUpLeave()" />
```

```js
  imgUpNeutral = '/assets/icons/up.png';
  imgUpHover = '/assets/icons/up-hover.png';
  imgUpActive = '/assets/icons/up-active.png';
  imgPathUp = this.imgUpNeutral;
  currentImgUp = this.imgPathUp;
  
  
  public onUpHover(): void {
    this.imgPathUp = this.imgUpHover;
  }

  public onUpLeave(): void {
    this.imgPathUp = this.currentImgUp;
  }
  
  public onUp(): void {
    if (this.vote === VoteEnum.neutral) { // use the logic you need
      this.vote = VoteEnum.up;
      this.imgPathUp = this.imgUpActive;
    } else {
      this.vote = VoteEnum.neutral;
      this.imgPathUp = this.imgUpNeutral;
    };
    this.currentImgUp = this.imgPathUp;
  }
```